# Entity only fetches only one item in a list from a many to many relationship

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities, User and Group. The relationship between the entities is `ManyToMany`. Group is the owning entity, and User is the referencing entity. The expected functionality is this;

1. When I fetch a group from database, it should return the group with a list. This works perfectly fine
2. When I fetch a user from database, it should return a user with a list of all the groups a user belongs to. This returns user correct user data, with one problem. The group list only contains 1 group instead of the entire list of groups.

I have checked the database, since I thought that maybe there may be a problem with how I was saving either entities. Database looks fine, and in fact, all records exist in the join table, and with the proper relationships. Wring a query in the query console returns me exactly the data I want. So no problem with data itself.

This is my `Group` Entity(Owning side)

```
@Builder
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "`group`")
public class Group extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "group_user",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    private Set<User> groupMembers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

This is my `User` Entity

```
@Builder
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupMembers", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Group.class)
    private Set<Group> groups;

}
```

I tried writing a custom native query(shown below) in my repository, but this also gives back a single item in the list.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM group_user gu JOIN `group` g ON gu.group_id = g.id WHERE gu.user_id = 3;", nativeQuery = true)
    Set<Group> findAllGroupsOfUser(@Param("userId") Long userId);
```

I also tried changing the type from `Set<Group> groups` to `List<Group> groups`, but it still returns a single item in list.

For additional clarity;
Here is the `UserRepository`

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    Optional<User> findById(Long id);

    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

}
```

And the `UserService` implementation method

```
    @Override
    public User getWithGroups(Long userId) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        User user = this.getUserById(userId).get();
        user.getGroups();
        return user;
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked that the data inside the database is correct and you should actually be getting more than 1 group?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the post body, I have checked and it returns all groups as expected.

Comment: Does `Group` class have a `@Entity` annotation? Thats the only thing I don't see

Comment: Yes it does, I think it missing in the description is a typo.

Comment: All examples seem to initialize both lists/sets that are involved in the mapping. So `private Set<Group> groups;` to `private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();` might be all thats needed

Comment: Just tried it, no change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249727/discussion-between-steve-otieno-and-xtremebaumer).

Comment: I can't see your Table definition in Database, but if you havn't constraint on your id column, then can happen, that your groups in database have same value in id column and then result will be exactly how you describe it